# Adding a string and an integer in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a 1 in front of my binary code and this is how I'm going about it:
if I have `0101`, for example, then I'd add a number with 4 zeroes, like 10000 so it would become 10101. Here's my code:

```
$fill = strlen($string);
$number = '1';
$add = str_pad($number, $fill, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$m1 = $string + $add;
```

The problem is the output for that is something like `1.random number e+Random number`

Answer (score 1):

assuming `$string` is your `"0101"` string, you could just do `$m1 = '1'.$string;`

Comment: I haden't figured on that since I was assuming I had to use math.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong because the length of the string is potentially variable and `str_pad` requires you to know the length.  This will work, but it doesn't look so elegant:

```
if (strpos($string, '0') === 0) {
   $string = '1' . $string;
}
```